# Design 3-to-8 decoder with enable using three 2-to-4 decoders and eight AND gates

Tags: homework, decoder

I want to design a 3 to 8 decoder with enable using three 2 to 4 decoders without enable and eight AND gates. How can I design it? I thought about it, but only 2 to 8 decoder comes out. I don’t know where to connect the other input and enable.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Do you know how to do it *with* `Enable` ?

Comment: Note, that you are *not* asked to implement the `enable` input. You just need 3 "select" inputs.

Comment: We can’t use enable as input, can we? Should i need to set input as 0?

Comment: You are asked to implement it with decoders that don't have `enable` input. And it does not mean that you need to add the `enable` input to your implementation, the opposite is true. Your implementation should have 3 select inputs and 8 outputs, that's all

Comment: If you have 8 AND gates, then you only need two of the decoders. And you get an `enable` function as well! (think "matrix")

Comment: Then, you mean I don’t need to add enable in implementation? Where should I add the other input? The implementation that I did has only two inputs. But, the inputs have to be three so I need to add one more input.